# Maximal ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Prove that $J=(x)$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Comment: I believe that since $x$ is an indeterminate and $y$ is a specific value, expressions like $gcd(x,y)$ don't really have much meaning

Comment: @ASKASK $y$ is a polynomial. The notation is a bit unfortunate, though.

Comment: It looks like you're proving that there exists a $y\in I\setminus J$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle=\mathbb{R}[x]$.  This is not the definition of a maximal ideal, *every* larger ideal must be the entire ring.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 4):

Note that we have a surjective morphism of rings ${\rm ev}_0:\Bbb R[X]\to \Bbb R$ with ${\rm ev}_0(p(X))=p(0)$. What is the kernel of this morphism? Since $\Bbb R$ is a field, what does this give?

Comment: Isn't $(x)$ is the kernel of that morphism? And since, $\mathbb{R}$ is a field, we can say $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x)$ is a field right? And, hence $J$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Comment: @abcd1234 Yes, it is *a* maximal ideal, but not *the* maximal ideal. For example, $(X-1)$ is another, and $(X^2+1)$ is yet another. In fact, maximal ideals correspond bijectively up to unit multipliers to the irreducible polynomials in $\Bbb R[X]$.

Comment: Thanks. But, how can we manually show that $J$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x]$, for example, letting another ideal in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and show that ideal is the whole ring itself like I did before? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Elementary proof: 
Let $M$ be an ideal of $\Bbb R[X]$ such that $J\subsetneq M\subseteq \Bbb R[X]$.
Let  $P=a_nX^n+\ldots+a_1X+a_0\in M\setminus J$ then $a_0\neq 0$ in particular 
$a_0=P-(a_nX^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1)X\in M$ hence $M=\Bbb R[X]$ ($M$ contain an invertible element ).

Answer (score 0):

Consider an ideal $I$ of $\mathbb{R}[x]$, such that $(x)\subset I$ such that $(x)$ is properly contained in $I$. So there is a polynomial $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n$ such that $a_0\neq 0$. Note that $f(x)-(a_1x+\cdots +a_nx^n)=a_0\in I$. But $a_0$ is a unit in $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Therefore $I=\mathbb{R}[x]$.